# Keep branches in separate SVN repositories up to date

Tags: svn, version-control

I have two separate SVN repositories both with trunk, branches, and tags directories.

Within the branches directory, I have several SW project branches which exist and need to be up to date with each other in both of the repositories;

for example branch prj1.br exists in Repo-A and Repo-B:

`Repo-A/branches/prj1.br`

`Repo-B/branches/prj1.br`

Using Subversion is there a proper way to keep these branches in different repositories up to date with each other via SVN commands which could be scripted?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you should use [vendor branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html), but I'm not sure just because it's unclear how branches in Repo-A and Repo-B are related.

Here is the current vendor branches management Python 3.3+ script http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/client-side/svn-vendor.py